# Converting binary string to a hexadecimal string JAVA

Tags: java, binary, hex, base-conversion

I want to convert my binary(which is in string) to hexadecimal string also, this is just a program fragment since this program is just a part of another bigger program:

```
//the variable name of the binary string is: "binary"
int digitNumber = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int test = binary.length()%4;
    if(test!=0) {
        binary = padLeft(binary, test);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
        if(digitNumber == 1)
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*8;
        else if(digitNumber == 2)
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*4;
        else if(digitNumber == 3)
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*2;
        else if(digitNumber == 4 || i < binary.length()+1){
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*1;
            digitNumber = 0;
            if(sum < 10)
                System.out.print(sum);
            else if(sum == 10)
                System.out.print("A");
            else if(sum == 11)
                System.out.print("B");
            else if(sum == 12)
                System.out.print("C");
            else if(sum == 13)
                System.out.print("D");
            else if(sum == 14)
                System.out.print("E");
            else if(sum == 15)
                System.out.print("F");
            sum=0;
        }
        digitNumber++;  
    }
    public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
        return String.format("%0$"+n+"s", s);
    }//i added this for padding
```

the problem is that i dont know if the padding works but i am sure that this program return a wrong hexadecimal conversion of the binary string I am trying to do this:

http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Binary-to-Hexadecimal

**PS: I need to implement it(not using any built-in function)**

Comment: The reason you're seeing nothing at all printed is that your loop condition (i==0) is not true at the beginning of the loop, so the loop never executes.  Once you fix that, however, there are many other things wrong with your code.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you don't have to implement that conversion yourself, you can use existing code :

```
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binaryStr,2);
String hexStr = Integer.toString(decimal,16);
```

If you must implement it yourself, there are several problems in your code :

1. The loop should iterate from 0 to binary.length()-1 (assuming the first character of the String represents the most significant bit).
2. You implicitly assume that your binary String has 4*x charcters for some integer x. If that's not true, your algorithm breaks. You should left pad your String with zeroes to get a String of such length.
3. `sum` must be reset to 0 after each hex digit you output.
4. `System.out.print(digitNumber);` - here you should print `sum`, not `digitNumber`.

Here's how the mostly fixed code looks :

```
    int digitNumber = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    String binary = "011110101010";
    for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
        if(digitNumber == 1)
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*8;
        else if(digitNumber == 2)
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*4;
        else if(digitNumber == 3)
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*2;
        else if(digitNumber == 4 || i < binary.length()+1){
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*1;
            digitNumber = 0;
            if(sum < 10)
                System.out.print(sum);
            else if(sum == 10)
                System.out.print("A");
            else if(sum == 11)
                System.out.print("B");
            else if(sum == 12)
                System.out.print("C");
            else if(sum == 13)
                System.out.print("D");
            else if(sum == 14)
                System.out.print("E");
            else if(sum == 15)
                System.out.print("F");
            sum=0;
        }
        digitNumber++;  
    }
```

Output :

`7AA`

This will work only if the number of binary digits is divisable by 4, so you must add left `0` padding as a preliminray step.

Comment: this is what I am trying to do 

http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Binary-to-Hexadecimal

Comment: @dumas You almost got it right, but you had several bugs, as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Use this for any binary string length:

```
String hexString = new BigInteger(binaryString, 2).toString(16);
```

Comment: BigInteger will trim leading zeros. This can be a problem if the bin string start with "00"

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this.

```
private void bitsToHexConversion(String bitStream){

    int byteLength = 4;
    int bitStartPos = 0, bitPos = 0;
    String hexString = "";
    int sum = 0;

    // pad '0' to make input bit stream multiple of 4 

    if(bitStream.length()%4 !=0){
         int tempCnt = 0;
         int tempBit = bitStream.length() % 4;           
         while(tempCnt < (byteLength - tempBit)){
             bitStream = "0" + bitStream;
             tempCnt++;
         }
    }

   // Group 4 bits, and find Hex equivalent 

    while(bitStartPos < bitStream.length()){
        while(bitPos < byteLength){
            sum = (int) (sum + Integer.parseInt("" + bitStream.charAt(bitStream.length()- bitStartPos -1)) * Math.pow(2, bitPos)) ;
            bitPos++;
            bitStartPos++;
        }
        if(sum < 10)
             hexString = Integer.toString(sum) + hexString;
        else 
             hexString = (char) (sum + 55) + hexString;

        bitPos = 0;
        sum = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Hex String > "+ hexString);
}
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class BinaryToHexadecimal
 {
      public static void main()
      {
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("enter the binary number");
         double s=sc.nextDouble();
         int c=0;
         long s1=0;
         String z="";
         while(s>0)
         {
           s1=s1+(long)(Math.pow(2,c)*(long)(s%10));
           s=(long)s/10;
           c++;
         }
         while(s1>0)
         {
           long j=s1%16;
           if(j==10)
           {
              z="A"+z;
           }
           else if(j==11)
           {
              z="B"+z;
           }
           else if(j==12)
           {
              z="C"+z;
           }
           else if(j==13)
           {
              z="D"+z;
           }
           else if(j==14)
           {
              z="E"+z;
           }
           else if(j==15)
           {
              z="F"+z;
           }
           else
           {
              z=j+z;
           }
           s1=s1/16;
      }
    System.out.println("The respective Hexadecimal number is : "+z);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

By given binary number `01011011`, we will convert it at first to decimal number, each number will be `Math.pow()` by decrementd length:

> 01011011 =(0 × 2(7)) + (1 × 2(6)) + (0 × 2(5)) + (1 × 2(4)) + (1 × 2(3)) + (0 × 2(2)) + (1 × 2(1)) + (1 × 2(0))
>
> = (0 × 128) + (1 × 64) + (0 × 32) + (1 × 16) + (1 × 8) + (0 × 4) + (1 × 2) + (1 × 1)
>
> = 0 + 64 + 0 + 16 + 8 + 0 + 2 + 1
>
> = 91 (decimal form of binary number)

Now after get decimal number we have to convert it to hexa-decimal-number.

So, 91 is greater than 16. So, we have to divide by 16.

After dividing by 16, quotient is 5 and remainder is 11.

Remainder is less than 16.

Hexadecimal number of remainder is B.

Quotient is 5 and hexadecimal number of remainder is B.

> That is, 91 = 16 × 5 +11 = **B**
>
> 5 = 16 × 0 + 5 = **5**
>
> =**5B**

**Implementation:**

```
String hexValue = binaryToHex(binaryValue);

    //Display result
    System.out.println(hexValue);


private static String binaryToHex(String binary) {
    int decimalValue = 0;
    int length = binary.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        decimalValue += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "") * Math.pow(2, length);
        length--;
    }
    return decimalToHex(decimalValue);
}
private static String decimalToHex(int decimal){
    String hex = "";
    while (decimal != 0){
        int hexValue = decimal % 16;
        hex = toHexChar(hexValue) + hex;
        decimal = decimal / 16;
    }
    return hex;
}

private static char toHexChar(int hexValue) {
    if (hexValue <= 9 && hexValue >= 0)
        return (char)(hexValue + '0');
    else
        return (char)(hexValue - 10 + 'A');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stringprocessing;

/**
 *
 * @author Zayeed Chowdhury
 */
public class StringProcessing {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int index = 0;
    String bin = "0000000101100101011011100110011100000001000000000000000010101010010101100110010101100011011010010110110101100001001000000100111001100101011101000111011101101111011100100110101101110011001000000100100001000001010100110010000001001001010100110101001101010101010001010100010000100000010000010010000001010010010001010101000101010101010010010101001001000101010001000010000001010111010001010100010101001011010011000101100100100000010101000100010101010011010101000010000001000110010011110101001000100000010101000100100001000101001000000100011001001111010011000100110001001111010101110100100101001110010001110010000001000011010011110101010101001110010101000100100101000101010100110010111101000001010100100100010101000001010100110011101000100000010100000110100101101110011000010110110000101100001000000100000101011010001110110010000001000001010101000010000000000001111000000011000100110010001110100011000100110011001000000101000001001101001000000100111101001110";
    String[] hexString = new String[bin.length() / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < bin.length() / 4; i++) {
        hexString[i] = "";
        for (int j = index; j < index + 4; j++) {
            hexString[i] += bin.charAt(j);
        }
        index += 4;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bin.length() / 4; i++) {
        System.out.print(hexString[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + bin.length());
    String[] result = binaryToHex(hexString);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("" + result[i].toUpperCase());
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static String[] binaryToHex(String[] bin) {
    String[] result = new String[bin.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(bin[i], 2));
    }
    //return Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(bin[0], 2));
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

private final String[] hexValues = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};

```
public void binaryToHexadecimal(String binary){
    String hexadecimal;
    binary  = leftPad(binary);
    System.out.println(convertBinaryToHexadecimal(binary));

}

public String convertBinaryToHexadecimal(String binary){
    String hexadecimal = "";
    int sum = 0;
    int exp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<binary.length(); i++){
        exp = 3 - i%4;
        if((i%4)==3){
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i)+"")*(int)(Math.pow(2,exp));
            hexadecimal = hexadecimal + hexValues[sum];
            sum = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i)+"")*(int)(Math.pow(2,exp));
        }
    }
    return hexadecimal;
}

public String leftPad(String binary){
    int paddingCount =  0;
    if ((binary.length()%4)>0)
        paddingCount = 4-binary.length()%4;

    while(paddingCount>0) {
        binary = "0" + binary;
        paddingCount--;
    }
    return binary;
}
```