# Binary String to Hex String

Tags: java, android, binary, hex

I want to turn a string of binary to hexadecimal string

For example, I have a length of 24 binary string

```
"000100000010000000110000"
```

Convert hex becomes `0x10 0x20 0x30`

How can I do?

I made reference to this: [http: //stackoverflow.com/questions/25592084/converting-binary-string-to-a-hexadecimal-string-java](http://I%20made%20reference%20to%20this:%20http:%20//stackoverflow.com/questions/25592084/converting-binary-string-to-a-hexadecimal-string-java)

But I tried the results are not correct ...

I was wrong in what I ask?

```
     int digitNumber = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        String binary = "00000001";
        for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++)
        {
            if(digitNumber == 1)
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*8;
            else if(digitNumber == 2)
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*4;
            else if(digitNumber == 3)
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*2;
            else if(digitNumber == 4 || i < binary.length()+1)
            {
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*1;
                digitNumber = 0;
                if(sum < 10)
                    System.out.print("0x"+sum);
                else if(sum == 10)
                    System.out.print("A");
                else if(sum == 11)
                    System.out.print("B");
                else if(sum == 12)
                    System.out.print("C");
                else if(sum == 13)
                    System.out.print("D");
                else if(sum == 14)
                    System.out.print("E");
                else if(sum == 15)
                    System.out.print("F");
                sum=0;
            }
            digitNumber++;  
        }
   }
```

The result is ...

```
0x00x1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592084/converting-binary-string-to-a-hexadecimal-string-java

Comment: And so far, you've tried...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592084/converting-binary-string-to-a-hexadecimal-string-java

I have made reference to the article, but I wanted to in front with 0x

I do not know how to start ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Integer.parseInt(binOutput, 2) instead of Integer.parseInt(binOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

//Here is my Solution:

```
package stringprocessing;

/**
 *
 * @author zayeed
 */

public class StringProcessing {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int index = 0;
        String bin = "0000000101100101011011100110011100000001000000000000000010101010010101100110010101100011011010010110110101100001001000000100111001100101011101000111011101101111011100100110101101110011001000000100100001000001010100110010000001001001010100110101001101010101010001010100010000100000010000010010000001010010010001010101000101010101010010010101001001000101010001000010000001010111010001010100010101001011010011000101100100100000010101000100010101010011010101000010000001000110010011110101001000100000010101000100100001000101001000000100011001001111010011000100110001001111010101110100100101001110010001110010000001000011010011110101010101001110010101000100100101000101010100110010111101000001010100100100010101000001010100110011101000100000010100000110100101101110011000010110110000101100001000000100000101011010001110110010000001000001010101000010000000000001111000000011000100110010001110100011000100110011001000000101000001001101001000000100111101001110";
        String[] hexString = new String[bin.length() / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < bin.length() / 4; i++) {
            hexString[i] = "";
            for (int j = index; j < index + 4; j++) {
                hexString[i] += bin.charAt(j);
            }
            index += 4;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bin.length() / 4; i++) {
            System.out.print(hexString[i] + " ");
        }

       // System.out.println("\n" + bin.length());
        String[] result = binaryToHex(hexString);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("" + result[i].toUpperCase());
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static String[] binaryToHex(String[] bin) {
        String[] result = new String[bin.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
            result[i] = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(bin[i], 2));
        }
        //return Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(bin[0], 2));
        return result;
    }

}
```